# What do we call a law that takes a number as input and returns a function?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

A law that turns a number to a number is called a function. A law that turns a function into a number is called a functional e.i. y=max(f(x)).
We call a law that converts a function into a function (e.i. a derivative) an operator.
What do we call a law that converts a number into a function?

Comment: A family of functions

Comment: At some point you stop inventing new names for these things, and call them all "functions".

Answer (score 1):

I would call something that maps functions to functions an operator. Differential operators are a class that is often studied.

The term function can be understood more generally. Essentially anything that maps from one space to another as long as each element from the first space is mapped to exactly one element of the second is a function. Either space could be just natural/ real/ etc numbers but could also be a space of functions or a space of matrices or something like that.

**Edit in response to comment**: A space of functions is usually much much bigger than a space of numbers. If you have a function that maps the real numbers to functions from real to real numbers only a tiny amount of the functions will be in the image of your mapping so this kind of things is rarely useful.

The only context where one would use something similar is if you have a family of functions parametrized by numbers. For example the family of functions $f_n(x)=x^n$ where $n$ is a natural number but I wouldn't really think of this as a mapping from numbers to functions.

Comment: While this is true... What do we call a thing that maps a number to a function. No, my job doesnot depend on this. Yes, I would love to know what we call this thing.

Comment: I am trying to Google something regarding number to function mapping (my specific question is too broad for math stackexchage). My search for a keyword "function" mostly yield number - > number maps, which are irrelevant for my task.

Answer (score 0):

We could call this law that converts a number into a function a representation. The representation is well-defined, if we restrict ourselfs to some subset of functions.

For example, given a number $k \in \mathbb{R}$ we can define a function $f(x) = k x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that represents the number $k$. In this trivial example, for the set of functions $\lbrace f(x) = kx$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R} \mid k \in \mathbb{R}\rbrace$, the inverse $f \mapsto k$ is bijective, i.e. there exists a unique $k \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $f(x) = kx$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. This is also a corollary of Riesz representation theorem.

Comment: Well, I am looking for a specific name for a number - > function rule because I am looking for a thing that simes to play a marginal role in my research. My supervisor mentioned the name of this law some 20 years ago. But he passed away and I have noone to help m3 with current research. I would love to know. The name of this thing.

Comment: Representations heavily depend on group theory. And there is no obvious connection of number - > function mapping in representation theory.